# rails accepts_nested_attributes and :reject_if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with nested attributes. Now in my `:reject_if =>` statement i would like to check an attribute on the nested model, say `first_record?` Is there a way to access such a method? It seems to me that you can only access the submitted attribute hash, to check if a field is blank for example. Thanks!

Comment: You should be aware that reject_if only rejects the changes to the nested attributes, it won't cause an error when saving the model with the bad nested attribute value. If you want to get an error on bad nested attributes just add the validation to your nested model and it will then throw an error when saving the parent model.

Answer (score 7):

According to docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Alternatively, :reject_if also accepts a symbol for using methods:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, :reject_if => :new_record?
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, :reject_if => :reject_posts

  def reject_posts(attributed)
    attributed['title'].blank?
  end
end
```

This should work for you. Basically that means that in custom function you can do  anything you want.

Comment: Yes, but the method called is on the Member model. I would like to call a method on the nested object being build. So for example i would like to say `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, :reject_if => post.first_record?` assuming that `Post` has a method `first_record?`. I'm not sure if the object being build is available like that, or if `:reject_if =>` is being called before the object is actually build...?

Comment: Well, i solved the actual problem another way. But i am still curious as to whether the nested object is available for `:reject_if`.